# React Froala Editor doesn't show paragraph drop down

Tags: reactjs, froala

I integrated React Froala Editor to my website.
It's a simple project and I want to show paragraph select drop down.
But it doesn't work.
Is it related to version?

```
this.state = {
    model: ``,
    tags: [],
    config: {
        theme: 'foobar',
        heightMax: 800,
        height: 800,
        toolbarButtons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', '|', 'paragraphStyle', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', 'undo', 'redo', 'html']
    }
}



<FroalaEditorComponent 
    model={this.state.model}
    onModelChange={this.onChange}
    config={this.state.config}
/>
```

[image]

Comment: that feature might not be available in the free version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that plugins are missing. Try to import plugins in your component:

```
import 'froala-editor/js/plugins.pkgd.min.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with the froala version you are using.
Please update Froala version using

> npm update froala-editor

All the options are available in the trail version too.
The same options worked for me with v3.1.0, check it below.

[Froala editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9Elj.png)